# Sending a variable from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I got a question about servlets and jsp.

Servlet:

```
public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        Integer i = new Integer(15);
        request.setAttribute("var", i);
        RequestDispatcher Dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        Dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

JSP page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form id="id" method="get" action="servlet">
            <%= (request.getAttribute("var")) %>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

As a result I expect to see 15, but I see null. Why does it happen?

Comment: Fixed it. The result is the same :(

Comment: Are both the servlet and the JSP contained in the same application (WAR, project...)?

Comment: yes, it's the same idea project

Comment: how ur accessing that index.jsp ...In web.xml   u have a entry like this <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>..Isn't it @user2246018?

Comment: right, give us the URL you test at...

Comment: I am almost sure ...your not giving chance to application for complete request-response cycle... u should access servlet first then only u can see that 15 on index.jsp other wise it will show you NULL definitely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Request parameters are sent from the view to the controller, request attributes are used to pass data in the current request to help build the new response. So, you [**should not use scriplets**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197) and access to the request attributes by using [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info):

```html
<body>
    <!-- No need to use a form for this page -->
    The request attribute: ${var}
</body>
```

Note that by your current request, you should perform a GET request on your servlet. Since your servlet name is *servlet* (which I suggest your to change it immediately), you should access to this URL:  `http://yourServerName/yourApplicationName/servlet`

Comment: Good suggestions all around.

Answer (score 0):

Use request.getAttribute("var");

Comment: I fixed it. And I still see "null"

Comment: May be surrounding brackets is the problem...cant check right now. Btw I would prefer Luiggi solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in the servlet but in struts 2 you need getter and setter method to sent data from jsp, you try this:

```
public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet 
{
    private Integer i;
    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        i = new Integer(15);
        request.setAttribute("var", i);
        RequestDispatcher Dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        Dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

  public Integer getI()
  {
     return i;
  }
  public void setI(Integer i)
  {
    this.i = i;
   }

 }//also lacked this
```